# Filter on more than one column

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a table that I can filter from one column:

```
  handleSearch: function(oEvent) {
                var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
                var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("RAG_SOC_1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
                var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
                oBinding.filter([oFilter]);
          },
```

How can I filter from more columns?

For example if I have the columns A, B, C and D, if I write "hello" in the search bar, I want all results that have in fields A or B or C or D the word "hello".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the following code:

```
var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("A", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("B", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
var oFilter3 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("C", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
var oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("D", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);
var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1,oFilter2,oFilter3,oFilter4]); 
var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
oBinding.filter(allFilter);
```

See [documentation:](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html)

new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilters, bAnd);

aFilters is an array of other instances of sap.ui.model.Filter. If bAnd is set all filters within the filter will be ANDed else they will be ORed.