# How to filter a table on multiple columns in SAPUI5

Tags: filtering, sapui5

I'm facing a problem in SAPUI5, I can't solve.

I got a table with a toolbar which contains a textfield. The value of that field is used to filter all columns of the table. 
I know, I have to create multiple custome filters. But I dont know, how to put all the pieces together. So I created a method like this:

```js
filtering : function(value, oEvent) {
    var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(this.byId("Column1"), sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
    var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(this.byId("Column2"), sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
    var oFilter3 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(this.byId("Column3"), sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
    var oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(this.byId("Column4"), sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
    var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2, oFilter3, oFilter4], false); 
    var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(allFilter);
}
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200955/filter-on-more-than-one-column)

The method is called from an liveChange event of the textfield. I dont know whether I need the oEvent.

What's the first parameter of "new sap.ui.model.Filter()"? I thought it's the columns, which's needed.
Where does the new filter has to be triggered? I would use the "table.filter(allFilter)".

I guess, I just  need a little explanation...

Comment: Hi @Gorch: I cannot see that you have accepted any answers on your question. Did one of the responses answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

1. Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 are the binding paths of your columns.
2. You don't need the `oEvent` for the filter.
3. You can't call `table.filter(allFilter)`, `table.filter(oEvent)` is an event handler and is fired when the table is filtered. You should call `filter` of `sap.ui.model.ListBinding` to filter table.

See the following code:

```js
liveChange:function(oEvent) {
    var newValue = oEvent.getParameter("liveValue");
    filtering(newValue);
},

filtering : function(value) {
   var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
   var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column2", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
   var oFilter3 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column3", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
   var oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column4", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value);
   var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2, oFilter3, oFilter4], false); 
   var oBinding = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
   oBinding.filter(allFilter);
}
```

Comment: It works. But I always get the error "Wrong parameters defined for filter. -". For the columns I changed the bind paths to the property that's bound to it. You got a clue, what's missing/wrong?

Comment: What do you mean it worked but throws error？Error in which line?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late response but I have just figured this out myself. You need a button to work with your textfield. Here's the code that should get it to work:

```
var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "find",
    styled: false,
    press: function () {
        var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column1",  sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oInput.getValue());
        var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column2", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oInput.getValue());
        var oFilter3 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column3", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oInput.getValue());
        var oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Column4", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oInput.getValue());
        var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2, oFilter3, oFilter4], oInput.getValue());
        oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(allFilter);
     }
}).placeAt("search");
```

You may have to change oInput to whatever you named your textfield. You may also have to change where you are placing the button. Here's the link that helped me with my solution http://jsbin.com/xinucunidi/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

to have a predicate that operates on the complete node of a model
I found out that you can pass: path: false in the oFilterInfo
e.g.

```
 new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path:false,
        test: function (oNode) {
            console.log("In filter");
            console.log(oNode);
          return true; // result may depend on all properties of the node
      }})
```

this info may or may not be helpful, it comes without any warranties;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in a blank string to the filter constructor to get access to the entire node.

Here is sample code to filter on client + contact using a custom filter function. This was used with suggest where hiding duplicates makes sense. You probably wont want to use this for filtering a table unless you really only want one row.

```
    //Help function to handle the suggest events of the client search field ## handles duplicates ! ##
handleSuggestClient: function(oEvent){
    var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
    var filters = [];
    var uniqueNames = [];
    filters = [new sap.ui.model.Filter([
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("", function(oNode) { // blank first param passes in entire node to test function
                var sVal = ((oNode.client + oNode.contact) || "").toUpperCase()
                if (uniqueNames.indexOf(sVal) === -1){
                    uniqueNames.push(sVal);
                    return sVal.indexOf(sValue.toUpperCase()) > -1;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
    ], false)];
    this.oSFClient.getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(filters);
    this.oSFClient.suggest();
},
```